# IPA doesn't work on iPad ios 6.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I create IPA files with xcode. They work on iPad iOS 4.3 and  work on iPhone. But they doesn't  work on iPad ios 6.0.1. On iPad  ios 6.0.1 First IPA doesn't launch. Second launch but doesn't show anything. What might be the problem?

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using?

Comment: Having some error messages would help both you and us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the newest iOS SDK (and update Xcode), the problem could be that ipa compiled with older sdk wont work on the device with newest ios system version.